# Can i make this code much simpler and much smaller? c#

Tags: c#

As you can see in the code bellow , i have 3 foreach statements and its kinda big code i think. The main difference is only in `FieldName`. I hope someone can make it simpler..

```
string fieldname;
string fieldLabel = "";

foreach (var u in data)
{
    fieldname = "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".name";
    if (u.Key == fieldname)
    {
        fieldLabel = u.Value.ToString();
    }
}

if (fieldLabel == "")
{
    fieldname = "field" + tag.getName() + ".name";
    foreach (var u in data)
    {
        if (u.Key == fieldname)
        {
            fieldLabel = u.Value.ToString();
        }
        if (fieldLabel == "")
        {
            fieldname = "field" + tag.getName() + ".name";
        }
    }
}

if (fieldLabel == "")
{
    fieldname = "field" + tag.getName()+ "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".components";
    foreach (var u in data)
    {
        if (u.Key == fieldname)
        {
            fieldLabel = u.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add foreach logic to a helper method

Comment: using String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldLabel) would be much cleaner instead fieldLabel == ""

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange code review site - that would be a better place for this question... https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What kind of container is `data`?

Comment: I haven't tried it ... but maybe ...
`label = data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == firstKeyPermutation || d.key == second..... )?.Value.Tostring()`

Comment: data is dictionary

Comment: then you can also use data.TryGetValue for each key permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirstOrDefault function will return the value of the first keyValuePair that fulfills the condition in the given order.

```
var fieldLabel = "";

var foundValue = data.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".name"
                                || kvp.Key == "field" + tag.getName() + ".name"
                                || kvp.Key == "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".components")
                     .Select(e => (string)e.Value)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundValue))
    fieldLabel = foundValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumming data is dictionary:

```
string fieldname = "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".name";
string fieldLabel = "";

if(!data.ContainsKey(fieldname))
    fieldname = "field" + tag.getName() + ".name";
if (!data.ContainsKey(fieldname))
    fieldname = "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".components";
if (data.ContainsKey(fieldname))
    fieldLabel = data[fieldname].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string fieldLabel = "";
string[] fieldnames = {
    "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".name",
    "field" + tag.getName() + ".name",
    "field" + tag.getName()+ "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".components"
};

foreach (var fieldname in fieldnames)
{
    foreach (var u in data)
    {
        if (u.Key == fieldname)
        {
            fieldLabel = u.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    if (fieldLabel != "") break;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
string fieldLabel = "";
string[] fieldnames = {
    "field" + tag.getName() + "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".name",
    "field" + tag.getName() + ".name",
    "field" + tag.getName()+ "[" + msg.getMtId().getMessageType() + "]" + ".components"
};

foreach (var fieldname in fieldnames)
{
    if (data.ContainsKey(fieldname))
    {
        fieldLabel = data[fieldname].ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```